# How to safely "reply" to spam email?

Tags: spam

I have received an email flagged as spam from Yahoo but it was strange since it contained part of my password. The email states that they know my password so I better pay them in BTC.
I think I had to change my password some years ago since Yahoo said it may have leaked, but I used the same base password with slight change, so my new once still contains the word that was quoted in the spam email.
Yahoo logs for sessions didn't show anyone else logging in recently so I changed my password to something completely different (oh, I already forgot it...) and also I changed my recovery email password, to be on the safe side.

Since the sender claims to have videos of me from my computer camera, but I don't have a camera, I feel safe knowing they have just my old password and I would like to send an email to the sender, but from a different email address.

Probably I should create a new email just for this purpose, but is there something else I should look for so that I don't get identified in any way?
Can I be traced by using for example Yahoo website to send an email?

*Of course I will not mention the specific data from the email that was sent to me*

Comment: This is a common spam method. Why do you want to contact them?

Comment: If you want to email someone and not be identified, use a temporary email or a disposable email account. I'm not sure how your Yahoo spam story applies to your desire to email this individual.

Comment: @schroeder For me it was the first time I see such spam method. I want to contact them in order to try to get more info about them, by still pretending to be a victim.
Ok, I guess it was a long description of the spam story.

After sending an email I would also like the possibility to receive a reply on that temporary email, so a disposable one (that is invalid after like 1h) is not a good candidate.

Comment: There are multiple definitions of "disposable"...

Comment: There is zero benefit to contacting them. If you want them investigated, then you need to submit the email to the police. You contacting them will only cause complications.

Answer (score 2):

> TL;DR
>
> Don't reply to spam emails

There are many databases where corporations had been exposed and your data in them. You can check your accounts on services like https://haveibeenpwned.com/.

When you reply to those emails you're also telling the spammer that your account it's still active and they can perform a direct attack on you, they also could try to hit you with different spam attempts than just reporting them.

And as a friendly reminder try to always use 2FA (Two Factor Authentication) and a password manager.